# Dart: convert Observable to Future and vice-versa?

Tags: dart, rxdart

How can I convert a Dart `Observable` to a `Future` and vice-versa?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To convert a `Observable` to a `Future`:

- `myObservable.first`
- `myObservable.firstWhere`

To convert a `Future` to an `Observable`:

- `Observable.fromFuture(myFuture)`

Or into a simple stream:

- `myFuture.asStream()`